# Does useEffect with dependency load on initial component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Does useEffect with dependencies load during initial mount of the component?

```
useEffect(() => {
       // Some Code
}, [somedependency]);
```

Or do I have to make another useEffect like this?

```
useEffect(() => {
           // Some Code
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all `useEffect()` will be called at the first mount. And subsequent calls happen only if React detects a change in the `dep`. So no need of `useEffect(() => {}, [])`